# I can't Add a new page in wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to add a new page in wordpress from wordpress dashboard,
it throw a warning message:

> warning: Creating default object from empty value in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 642

I disabled plugins but I still have the same bug and I can't add a page.

Comment: Perhaps try with a the default Wordpress theme to see if you're getting the same error there.

Comment: Try switching to a default theme. And also check your current theme's functions.php

Comment: I still had the same error when I changed to default theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by run this code in ubuntu terminal:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the files of deleted plugin stored in the Database this will help to completely remove the

Other ways :

Delete Unwanted tables created by plugin in PhpMyadmin